# Can a GCP organization only have one org policy?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am not at all versed in organization policy administration, apologies if my question has an obvious answer.

I tried defining a `google_access_context_manager_access_policy` via terraform,

```
resource "google_access_context_manager_access_policy" "org-policy" {
  parent   = data.google_organization.org.name
  title    = "Parent policy for ACL restrictions"
}
```

but I get this error :

```
╷
│ Error: Error creating AccessPolicy: googleapi: Error 409: Policy already exists with parent organizations/<my-org-id>
│
│   with google_access_context_manager_access_policy.org-policy,
│   on policies.tf line 1, in resource "google_access_context_manager_access_policy" "org-policy":
│    1: resource "google_access_context_manager_access_policy" "org-policy" {
│
╵
```

When I perform this command : `gcloud access-context-manager policies list --organization <my-org-id>` I see that there is a default org policy (that has never been explicitely set)

```
NAME          ORGANIZATION   SCOPES  TITLE           ETAG
<redacted-id> <my-org-id>            default policy  <what-s-even-this>
```

Can I create another **organization** policy upon which I could base all further dependent policies? e.g. `google_access_context_manager_access_level`

If I can't, how do I redefine the default org policy?

P.S : I'm not sure what tags (community) to invoke for this question. Please advise.

Edit :

Terraform & `hashicorp/google` versions !

`Terraform v1.2.9`

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = ">=3.85.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include the Terraform HCL.

Comment: @JohnHanley, done. Apologies

Comment: Same error here (trying to deploy pci-gke-blueprint)

Comment: Which version of the `hashicorp/google` module are you using?

Comment: @BenoîtSauvère, I've included that in the edit above

Answer (score 1):

Think I've found out: [you can only have one policy on a particular level](https://cloud.google.com/access-context-manager/docs/scoped-policies#:%7E:text=Organizations%20can%20only%20have%20one%20access%20policy%20at%20the%20organizational%20level%2C%20and%20you%20can%20apply%20the%20organizational%2Dlevel%20access%20policy%20to%20any%20folder%20or%20project%20in%20your%20organization.)

As your organisation already have one by default you can only create new policies on folder/project.

Assuming you have the latest `terraform-google-modules` version

```
resource "google_access_context_manager_access_policy" "org-policy" {
  parent = data.google_organization.org.name
  title  = "Parent policy for ACL restrictions"
  scopes = ["folders/00000000000000"]
}
```

Comment: Hmm... any idea how to replace the default policy?